# Graph of energy stored in capacitor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, capacitance

Question: In an experiment a capacitor is discharged through a constant current. Draw a graph of how the energy stored in the capacitor varies with time.

The answer given is:

[image]

But I seemed to get a different answer:

[image]

I know my graph is counter-intuitive since if you are discharging a capacitor it has to start off with a nonzero energy stored, so my graph being 0 at t=0 is contradictory. However, my working seemed to show that my answer is correct, so I want to know where I went wrong.

Basically for constant current we have $Q=It$ proportional to $t$, i.e. $Q$ proportional to $t$. Then since $V$ proportional to $Q$, we must have: $V$ proportional to $Q$ proportional to $t$, i.e. $V$ proportional to $t$. Therefore, the energy stored, which is given by $E=\frac{1}{2}QV$, is proportional to $t^2$,  This means that $E=kt^2$ for some constant $k$. So it is a parabola like the one I showed.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The equation $Q=It$ is incorrect, since $Q$ should be nonzero when $t=0$.

Comment: @leongz: It must be, thanks! If you write an answer I'll accept quickly. (Please also include how the correct graph is found if you decide to write answer)

Comment: Alternatively, you can write up your own answer, and show us how you can get correct graph.

Comment: @leongz: But I don't know how. You only told me that Q=It is wrong but I don't see what else I can use. Maybe it is the fact that it is being discharged so I is negative, but I don't see how that implies a negative gradient unless we had V=kxt with k being a *positive* constant.

Comment: Try starting with $Q=Q_0-It$, where $Q_0$ is the initial charge the capacitor has.

Comment: @leongz: Thanks, but I don't remember seeing that before. Is it related to the Q=Q_0*e^(-t/RC) equation? Do we only use Q=Q_0-It when the current is constant and the capacitor is being discharged? Sorry, just a bit confused here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23417/discussion-between-leongz-and-user45220).

Comment: @leongz: I finished the answer, and thank you again for helping me understand

Answer (score 2):

I understand the problem now from leongz's excellent explanation and patience in the chat discussion. Thank you very much leongz for helping me out!

The capacitor is being discharged through constant current. If it starts with charge $Q_0$, then from the definition of current we know that the charge decreases by It after time t, where I is the constant current. So $Q=Q_0-It$.

We want the graph of energy, so we use $E=0.5\times Q\times V$. Then we can eliminate V by using $C=Q/V$ to get $V=Q/C$. Putting this into $E=0.5\times Q\times V$ gives $E=(0.5/C)(Q^2)$.

But from before, $Q=Q_0-It$, so $E=(0.5/C)(Q_0-It)^2$.

We see that:

At $t=0$ this gives $E=(0.5/C)(Q_0)^2$, which is a positive $y$-intercept.

At $E=0$ we must have $Q_0-It=0$ which gives $t=Q_0/I$, which is positive $x$-intercept.

And also the graph is parabolic since the variable $t$ has degree 2.

Combining this we see that the graph is like the one in the answer.